# UserDetails: Password should only be mandatory for basic users

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

For basic users who want to log in, I have the following class:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BasicUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    @NotBlank(message = "Username is mandatory")
    @Email(message = "Username should be a valid email address")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password is mandatory")
    @Size(min = 8, message = "Password length should be at least 8 characters")
    private String password;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private boolean enabled;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password; 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

I now also have OAuth users. Since they never enter a password, the `password` property should not be mandatory. So `password` should be mandatory for basic users only but not for OAuth users. To resolve this issue, this is what I have tried:

**For OAuth Users**

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OAuthUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    @NotBlank(message = "Username is mandatory")
    @Email(message = "Username should be a valid email address")
    private String username;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private boolean enabled;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return "OAuthUserPassword"; // Just a placeholder since OAuth will not need a password
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

**For Baisic Users**

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BasicUserDetails extends OAuthUserDetails {
    @NotBlank(message = "Password is mandatory")
    @Size(min = 8, message = "Password length should be at least 8 characters")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

My problem is the following:

```java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserService implements UserDetailsService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (null == user || ! user.getUsername().equals(username)) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user present with username: " + username);
        }
        else {

            return new BasicUserDetails(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")), true);
        }
    }

}
```

There I get the error:

> Cannot resolve constructor 'BasicUserDetails(String, String, List,
> boolean)'

Probably because `BasicUserDetails` accepts password only as parameter, but how do I pass the rest of the parameters?

Comment: Add the constructor manually instead of using lombok?

Comment: "Probably because"? Instead of guessing, look at the generated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it:

```java
public BasicUserDetails(String username, String password, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities, boolean enabled) {
    super(username, authorities, enabled); // <-- Passing the parameters to OAuthUserDetails
    this.password = password;
}
```